# Making seamless, scalable objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to make a level/levels for a game, and the walls are my biggest challenge, because I have to re-scale textures every time I make a new wall of a different size.

Is there a way to have a texture scale automatically when I change the size? For example, I properly scaled the texture on the middle wall (see image), but the smaller (left) and larger (right) walls have skewed textures. I want these to mimic the scale of the middle wall. Is there a node for this?

Thanks!

[image]

EDIT:

New node still doesn't help:

EDIT:

Blend file uploaded here:
http://www.filedropper.com/walltesting_2

[image]

Still not working with new texture:
[image]

I was playing around with settings, but I can't seem to get it to work (thats why flat was selected). Even with BOX, still doesnt work :/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I should note that the solution here:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22872/unwrap-uv-map-proportionally-to-object-size 

does not work for me. It just causes the texture to become very squished, and I can't change the scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using [Position](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45149/5705) texture coordinates.

Just use the *Position* output of the *Input* > *Geometry* node for your texture coordinates.  This uses absolute world-space instead of the scaled local-space, so the textures will not be stretched.  To get it to map from all directions, select *Box* on the image texture node.

[image]

Comment: Still not working, see edit. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Vranvs  That's strange, box mapping should have fixed that.  Let me try something.

Comment: @Vranvs  Is it possible you could [upload your .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) (or just the relevant parts of it) so I could take a look at it?

Comment: Added a link to my blend file.. see edit. :)

Comment: Crap, Im not sure how to include the material with the file

Comment: @Vranvs  Go to file > External Data > Pack all into .blend.  (In playing with your file I just used a different texture and it worked fine.)

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/walltesting_2

Comment: Okay, I will try a different texture

Comment: @Vranvs  In that file you still had *Flat* selected on the texture, I changed it to *Box* and it [worked fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bPabC.jpg).

Comment: What the hell am I doing wrong?? I'm copying your settings exactly and can't get that result (See 3 new pics above)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36591/discussion-between-vranvs-and-pgmath).