# How to align UV maps on differently sized objects for seamlessness between each one?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've been looking for an answer on this and I'm utterly confused. I'm **very** new to UV mapping (in fact, this is my first "real" attempt to use it in a way that it tiles correctly) and I've got a problem with trying to get a texture to scale, too. I've tried even the different tools like TexTools and UV Magic, and I'm *still* not getting a 100% match on this on TexTools, for example. I have yet to try UV Magic, but from another thread (here: [Unwrap UV map proportionally to object size](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22872/unwrap-uv-map-proportionally-to-object-size)) there's no difference in the function of TexTools vs UV Magic? I'm not sure what is going on here... I tried the projection from view, but that creates a disaster for someone new like me. Isn't there a better way to do this?

Ok, so more details on this:
I have two items. Both are at a scale of 1.0 but have different widths and lengths. I've got a texture on them now, but it doesn't align. Below is what I'm working with:

[image]

Now, I've scaled both by 2.9x from the corner of the UV map using Smart UV Project.

[image]
[image]

Here's the thing... despite both being scaled by 2.9x, they are STILL different sizes and I can't get them to align. Here's the zoomed in version:
[image]
And here's the zoomed out version:
[image]

I hope this is not a duplicate topic! If it is, I apologize. Please lead me to the right one. I spent quite a while searching for a topic similar to this, and I've not been successful in finding an answer.

Here's what I want to do, but it requires overlapping geometry and a size change to make it work. Ideally, I'd like to not over-lap and keep the items of different sizes as they were originally:
[image]

Comment: Checkout the *Texture Atlas* addon.

Comment: Please tell me more? What exactly can I do with it? How would I go about doing what I'm trying to do with it?

Comment: [Texture Atlas](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas/) is an addon to temporarily combine objects for unwrapping them onto the same uvmap. After the UV process is finished, they are separated again, retaining their original transformations.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. That's useful; I will definitely look into it. I'd like any method possible to figure out this issue of mine since I know that there are multiple ways of doing this.